# How to save Product details in Multiple Databases at single time

Tags: sql, database

i have a sever with two different databases.

```
i.e DATABASE-1
    DATABASE-2
```

in my application am connected with `DATABASE-1.`

here i need when am saving a product details, it should also save in `DATABASE-2` of table. is it possible.?

Comment: The answer to the question, as it's currently written, is "probably." But your question doesn't include nearly enough detail to give a more specific answer. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for assistance.

Comment: you can do a cross database query / insert if you want to by fully qualifying the table name. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207559/how-to-execute-store-procedure-for-another-db

Comment: @Jeremy: that depends totally on the DBMS product that is being used. "SQL" is a query language, not the name of a specific database product